# Fastest performing way to JOIN a temp table to multiple columns in T-SQL

Tags: join, sql-server-2000

I need to write a SQL query to filter a table on 4 potential columns from another table of the filter values.

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
-- This table could have anywhere from 1 to 2000 possible rows
DECLARE @WidgetOwners TABLE (OwnerID INT PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @WidgetOwners VALUES (5)
INSERT INTO @WidgetOwners VALUES (50)
INSERT INTO @WidgetOwners VALUES (111)
INSERT INTO @WidgetOwners VALUES (12345)
INSERT INTO @WidgetOwners VALUES (6)
--etc...

SELECT w.WidgetID
FROM Widgets w
WHERE w.SellerManagerID IN (SELECT o.OwnerID FROM @WidgetOwners)
OR w.SellerID IN (SELECT o.OwnerID FROM @WidgetOwners)
OR w.BuyerManagerID IN (SELECT o.OwnerID FROM @WidgetOwners)
OR w.BuyerID IN (SELECT o.OwnerID FROM @WidgetOwners)
```

I am under the impression that the SUB SELECTS in the query above will not perform very well. Is there a better way to do this?  Could this be done by LEFT JOINING the @WidgetOwner table multiple times?  Does anyone have any recommendations here?

Keep in mind that I am stuck with SQL 2000 right now and cannot upgrade at the moment.

**EDIT - Example 2 (This is something else I am trying)**

```
SELECT w2.WidgetID, w2.* -- etc
FROM (
    SELECT w.WidgetID
    FROM Widgets w
    INNER JOIN @WidgetOwners o ON w.SellerManagerID = o.OwnerID
    UNION
    SELECT w.WidgetID
    FROM Widgets w
    INNER JOIN @WidgetOwners o ON w.SellerID = o.OwnerID
    UNION
    SELECT w.WidgetID
    FROM Widgets w
    INNER JOIN @WidgetOwners o ON w.BuyerManagerID = o.OwnerID
    UNION
    SELECT w.WidgetID
    FROM Widgets w
    INNER JOIN @WidgetOwners o ON w.BuyerID = o.OwnerID
) x
INNER JOIN Widgets w2 ON x.WidgetID = w2.WidgetID
```

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that table variables do not have statistics maintained and the Query Optimiser always assumes they will contain one row. How many rows are in `Widgets`? i.e. what proportion of rows will typically be returned by the query?

Comment: Approximately 2 million rows in Widgets, but it grows by a few thousand every day.  Would a temp table be better?

Comment: Worth trying and looking at the plans for both the case where the table has 1 row and where it has 2,000 rows. Are the 4 columns indexed?

Comment: All 4 columns are indexed.  I am currently looking at the plans.  I was asking more theoretically if anyone has experience trying to do this type of join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many rules of thumb in building efficient queries. But, I would suggest, when performance is a concern, it's always best to experiment with different approaches and to see in practice what performs best. Especially when row counts are large.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you try outer joins:

```
SELECT o1.ownerid, o2.ownerid, o3.ownerid, o4.ownserid
    ... 
FROM widgets w
LEFT JOIN o AS o1 ON w.SellerManagerID = o.OwnerID
LEFT JOIN o AS o2 ON w.SellerID = o.OwnerID
LEFT JOIN o AS o3 ON  w.BuyerManagerID = o.OwnerID
LEFT JOIN o AS o4 ON w.BuyerID = o.OwnerID
```

If helpful, (not knowing your requirement,) 
you can use

```
COALESCE(o1.OwnerID, o2.OwnerID, o3.ownerID, o4.ownerID)
```

or

```
CASE WHEN o1.ownerID IS NULL THEN ...
```

In my experience outer joins are nearly always as efficient as any other option, especially compared to  correlated subqueries.

I also worry when you mention "temp table".

Comment: In SQL Server correlated sub queries (talking about semi joins or anti semi joins here) are typically more efficient than joins. And why do you worry when he says `temp table`? The OP is already using a table variable.

Comment: your example doesnt solve the problem of filtering.  I need to filter the Widget table by the values in the Owner table.

Comment: correlated subqueries - here is but one reference: http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/06/correlated-sub-queries-for-good-or-evil.html. Yes, "already using" is what I am conerned about.

Comment: I did specifically say semi joins and anti semi joins. A couple of other links. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/ http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/